# Using Localhost in Delphi

Tags: lazarus, freepascal

Evening everyone,

The ideology was given yesterday so, i have been taking my time to learn delphi.
I want to send data vis URL (using GET request / Wininet) now i have problems using the http://localhost in delphi program, as when i try to use the localhost like this http://localhost, it comments the other instructions to be concatenated

I am using Lazarus , and my code goes like this

```
program InfoWininet;

{$mode delphi}{$H+}

uses
  {$IFDEF UNIX}{$IFDEF UseCThreads}
  cthreads,
  {$ENDIF}{$ENDIF}
  Classes , Windows , Wininet
  { you can add units after this };

var
  FirstName : string;
  LastName: string;
  Email: string ;
  IDNumber: string;
  IOpen, IURL: HINTERNET;
  Read: Cardinal;
  data: string;
  Result : string;
  http : HINTERNET;

begin
    Writeln('Enter Your First Name: ');
    Readln(FirstName);
    Writeln('Enter your Last Name: ');
    Readln(LastName);
    Writeln('Enter Your Email: ');
    Readln(Email);
    Writeln('Enter your ID Number: ');
    Readln(IDNumber);

    data := http://localhost/data.php?fname=' + FirstName + '&lastName=' + LastName + '&Email=' + Email +  '&IdNumber=' + IDNumber;
   begin
    Result:='';
    try
     IOpen := InternetOpen('Oxysys',INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, '', '',INTERNET_FLAG_NEED_FILE);
      if IOpen<>nil then
        try
        IURL:= InternetOpenUrl(IOpen, data, nil, 0,INTERNET_FLAG_DONT_CACHE, 0);
    if IURL<> nil then
        try
          SetLength(data,4096);
        repeat
    if InternetReadFile(IURL,@data[1],4096,Read) then
    Result:=Result + Copy(data,1,Read)
        else
        Break;
    until Read = 0;
    finally
      InternetCloseHandle(IURL);
    end;
    finally
      InternetCloseHandle(IOpen);
        end;
          except
    end;
          Writeln('Message Sent Successfully...');
          Readln;
end;
end.
```

Question is i get the following errors, when trying to compile my program

```
InfoWininet.lpr(33,13) Warning: Variable "http" does not seem to be initialized
InfoWininet.lpr(33,13) Error: Incompatible types: got "Pointer" expected "AnsiString"
InfoWininet.lpr(33,17) Fatal: Syntax error, ";" expected but ":" found
```

What could really be the problem? Can someone pls help, in correcting the problem, pls Am trying to learn Delphi Very well.

Comment: Aren't you missing an apostrophe before `http://...`?

Answer (score 1):

```
data := http://localhost/data.php?fname=' + FirstName + '&lastName=' + LastName + 
  '&Email=' + Email +  '&IdNumber=' + IDNumber;
```

You have failed to wrap your string literal in quotes. It should be:

```
data := 'http://localhost/data.php?fname=' + ....
        ^
    quote missing here
```

Comment: Another Question that demands clarity. I wanted to make use of a program that uses Resource for instance , now the first .exe file is loaded into the second viz resource ,  i wanted it to be something like a Builder and stub thing,
Now the stub is suppose to fetch the URL from the builder and then use the URL in its function as the case maybe. 
if am to use the URL from the main builder file, do i do it like this 

data := 'textBox1.text' + FirstName + '&lastName=' + LastName + '&Email=' + Email +  '&IdNumber=' + IDNumber;

Comment: I don't know. I thought you were asking about the compiler error.